No rule to process file '/.../main.jsbundle' of type 'text' for architecture 'arm64'
Since I have updated my mac to maOS Sequoia (15), I had to update XCode to 16. Since, my iOS build fails with the following:
▸ Compiling PrivateSentrySDKOnly.mm
▸ Compiling React-nativeconfig-dummy.m
    Run script build phase 'Start Packager' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this issue, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'project' from project 'project')
    Run script build phase 'Bundle React Native code and images' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this issue, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'project' from project 'project')
    Run script build phase 'Upload Debug Symbols to Sentry' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this issue, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'project' from project 'project')
    Run script build phase '[CP-User] [RNFB] Core Configuration' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this issue, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'project' from project 'project')
    no rule to process file '/Users/user/Documents/project/project/ios/main.jsbundle' of type 'text' for architecture 'arm64' (in target 'project' from project 'project')
    Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this issue, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'fmt' from project 'Pods')
    Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this issue, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Yoga' from project 'Pods')
    Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this issue, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'ReactCommon' from project 'Pods')
    Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this issue, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'React-utils' from project 'Pods')
    Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this issue, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'React-runtimescheduler' from project 'Pods')
    Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this issue, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'React-rendererdebug' from project 'Pods')
    Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this issue, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'React-nativeconfig' from project 'Pods')
    Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this issue, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'React-jserrorhandler' from project 'Pods')
    Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this issue, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'React-graphics' from project 'Pods')
    Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this issue, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'React-debug' from project 'Pods')
    Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this issue, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'React-NativeModulesApple' from project 'Pods')
    Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this issue, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'React-Mapbuffer' from project 'Pods')
    Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this issue, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'React-ImageManager' from project 'Pods')
    Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this issue, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'React-FabricImage' from project 'Pods')
    Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this issue, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'React-Fabric' from project 'Pods')
    Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this issue, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'React-Codegen' from project 'Pods')
    Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this issue, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'RCT-Folly' from project 'Pods')

The only thing I can extract is:
no rule to process file '/Users/user/Documents/project/project/ios/main.jsbundle' of type 'text' for architecture 'arm64' (in target 'project' from project 'project')


It really helps to downvote without explanation, thanks

Fixed by building with XCode which gave more detailed error: a lib (pod) had to be upgrade
